# svg mask over dotted line

Tags: css, svg

I have an svg path with a dotted line to show progress. What I would like is that I can create a mask that fills in `x` amount of dots and to have the rest be a lighter color.. this would show progress.

The issue I'm currently having is that the dots are not being filled in properly and I'm finding it hard to tweak it to where it works perfectly. I've added the code below.

This is what it should look like:

[image]

As you can see the path is being filled in.

Here is my code so far:

```css
body {
    background:#171B42;
}

.locked {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 76px auto;
  width: 230px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 180px;
}

.locked img {
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0 26px;
}

.locked.row-1 svg {
    width: 163px;
    height: 175px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -130px;
    right: -50px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
    <div class="locked row-1">
      
        <svg viewBox="0 0 163 175">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect fill="black" x="0" y="0" width="515" height="515"></rect>
      <path stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="0 20" fill="white" d="M0 16.7246C54 16.7246 145.7 11.6246 146.5 85.2246C147.3 158.825 51 158.225 0 158.225"></path>
    </mask>
    <path id="path" fill="none" d="M0 16.7246C54 16.7246 145.7 11.6246 146.5 85.2246C147.3 158.825 51 158.225 0 158.225"></path>
  </defs>
           <!-- solid wide line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.05)" stroke-width="30"></use>
  <!-- solid narrow line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.12)" stroke-width="15"></use>
  <!-- dotted full line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.2)" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="0 20" stroke-linecap="round"></use>
  <!-- dotted masked line -->
  <use href="#path" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,0.8)" stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="0 20" stroke-linecap="round" mask="url(#mask)"></use>
        
</svg>

      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/h3ElY2f_d.webp?maxwidth=728&fidelity=grand">
    </div>
    
  </div>
```

Any idea on how to properly apply the mask? Thank you

Comment: Refer to [this post](https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/guide-svg-animation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved to have the result that you needed by replacing the commented line by the one below :

```
<!-- <path stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-dasharray="0 20" fill="white" d="M0 16.7246C54 16.7246 145.7 11.6246 146.5 85.2246C147.3 158.825 51 158.225 0 158.225"></path> -->
<path stroke="white" stroke-width="5" fill="none" d="M0 16.7246C54 16.7246 145.7 11.6246 146.5 85.2246C147.3 158.825 51 158.225 0 158.225"></path>
```

The fact that you used the `fill="white"` instead of the `stroke="white"` constrained the masked circles to the shape drawed by the path, while your other lines were using the outline path that's defined in the `<path id="path" fill="none">` part.

Comment: Hmm, this does fill in the path, but the desired effect is that the path can be used as a progress so not all dots are filled in... do you know how that can be achieved?

Comment: for this kind of effect I usually use the gsap plugin drawSVG, and you can also do it using jquery's drawsvg feature, but I think you could do it natively by calculating the width of your path and then playing with the `stroke-dashoffset`  and `stroke-dasharray` values

Comment: Yeah I've been trying this but I'm unable to get any effect, been trying `<path stroke-dasharray="0 20" stroke-dashoffset="5" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" fill="none" d="M0 16.7246C54 16.7246 145.7 11.6246 146.5 85.2246C147.3 158.825 51 158.225 0 158.225"></path>` any more accurate idea?

Comment: @Simon for example, if I had ` stroke-dashoffset="400" stroke-dasharray="400 400"` to the path, and then change the values of `stroke-dashoffset` toward 0, I'm can see the path fill up!

Comment: You should use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getTotalLength#:~:text=getTotalLength()%20method%20returns%20the,which%20the%20SVGPathElement%20inherits%20it. in order to get the total length of your svg path. Then, you'd only have to set the value to `stroke-dasharray`, and vary your `stroke-dashoffset` values from the length value to 0.